# Why does element style override class that is set on element?

Tags: html, css, overriding

Our problem is like this.
We have piece of code like this.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <a href="#" class="child_item" onclick="return false;" onfocus="blur();">Item 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <a href="#" class="child_item" onclick="return false;" onfocus="blur();">Item 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <a href="#" class="child_item" onclick="return false;" onfocus="blur();">Item 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <a href="#" class="child_item" onclick="return false;" onfocus="blur();">Item 4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is all in global container with class `.content`.

CSS code:

```
.content a
{
    font-size: 11px;
}

.parent a
{
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

For some reason, instead of applying `.parent a`, browsers are applying `.content a`.
What is wrong and how come container CSS is applied instead of closer .parent a CSS?

Comment: They *should* get `.parent a` since it is of equal specificity, defined last, and overrides every property in `.content a`. It looks like you may have created a reduced test case that has reduced away the bug.

Comment: consider a scenario where parent and child both have there own characteristic. child may inherit property from its parent as well as can have its own property. if child and parent share same property than child's property take preference.

Comment: Is this happening only in some browsers? Do you have firebug, a browser plugin for firefox which explains how and why CSS has been applied?

Comment: I have this issue in Chrome, FF and IE (7,8).
It looks like `.parent a` is not applied

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both rules have the same specificity, so whichever rule comes last in the style declarations will win... Are you sure that the `.parent a`-rule is specified **after** the `.content a`-rule?

Another way to solve it would be to increase the specificity slightly, i.e:

`.parent .child_item {
   font-size: 16px;
}`

*Edit*: You can play around with your test case here: http://jsfiddle.net/gburw/
To prove my point, try switching the CSS-declarations and you will see that whichever rule is defined last will "win".

*Edit 2*: You can [read more about CSS specificity here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). It's a pretty simple concept to grasp, the hard part is avoiding specificity wars with fellow developers =) So you should come up with a standard way you write CSS in your company. Following the guidelines of Pagespeed and YSlow is also always a good idea.

Comment: Rule `.parent a` is second in file. As I understand it should be applied.
I also tried with solution you proposed, but still not working.

Comment: Hi, I read about CSS specifity and it helped. You were right, after all.
It can be used both your solution and `.parent a` solution.
I still do not know why browsers didn't want to display as we set it.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you really want `.parent a` to be applied. You can do this:

```
.parent a{
   font-size:16px !important;
}
```

that will give it more weight than `.content a` regardless of which was declared last.

Comment: Using !important is a horrendous practice. It can (almost) always be avoided, and ALWAYS leads to specificity wars. "Well well... X thinks he's so clever. I will double-important my rule and throw in a few ID-selectors to just for good measure! Take that, puny important rule!"

Comment: It sucks that every single specificity question has to be answered with an obligatory "use `!important`". Harsh reality.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue of [CSS Specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). Check to make sure that your CSS selectors are actually:

```
.content a
{
    font-size: 11px;
}

.parent a
{
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

and not someting like `#container .content a`. You could also increase the specificity of `.parent a` to `.parent .child a` if that's not the case.